# Using .offset().top with .slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, offset, slideup

I'm trying to make the window scroll to an element on click. It is working, except when the slideUp animation of one of the previous elements fires, the clicked element scrolls up way past the top.

**Here's the link:** http://jtwebfolio.com/mobi

**NOTE:** Size your browser down to mobile width to best see the issue. Also, this is taking place on the portfolio projects.

**Here's the code:**

```
$('article.project header').click(function(){

    if($(this).parent().hasClass('clicked')){
        // If the clicked project has already been clicked, remove the class and hide the content
        $(this).parent().removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).parent().find('.proj_content').slideUp('fast');
    }else{
        // Remove the class and slide the content up on all projects
        $('article.project').removeClass('clicked');
        $('article.project .proj_content').slideUp('fast');

        // Add the class and show the content on the selected project
        $(this).parent().addClass('clicked');
        $(this).parent().find('.proj_content').slideDown('fast');

        // Slide the project to the top after clicking on it
        $('html, body').delay(500).animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top
        }, 500);
    }

});
```

If someone could help me produce the desired effect, that would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect the solution is to put your scrolling inside of a callback function for the slideDown rather than using the delay method.  You are likely having timing issues.

Comment: Sweet site, really nice colours too :)

Comment: On a side note, your footer with the sidebar open is 70% but the sidebar is 200px, needs sorting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Your `.slideDown()`s use the speed `fast`, but you're only delaying by `500`ms. `fast` is synonymous with `600`ms. In general, I think it's a bad idea to use both as it's very confusing to someone reading your code what `fast` is.
- Rather than using `.delay()` method, I'd use the `complete` argument on the `slideDown` or `slideUp`s, so that once they're complete, you do your scrolling. This makes more sense, as you'd then not have to worry about conflicting timings.
- My guess would be that your problem is caused by your transitions taking 600ms, but your scroll only waiting 500ms. At 500ms, it's getting the wrong offset values and scrolling to those.
- Perhaps you should consider changing your markup to something like:

  ```
  $(this).parent().find('.proj_content').slideDown('600', function() {
    // Slide the project to the top after clicking on it
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
  ```

* Note: I've changed `fast` to `600` for clarity's sake.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the offset values combined with either slideUp or slideDown, but I wasn't sure how to execute my line of thought. This is exactly what I needed, though! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Any time! :) As I said on your question, the site's looking really nice - **fix your footer**!

Comment: I appreciate the compliment on the site! :)I'm not sure what is wrong with the footer, though. The 200px ensures that you can see that partial sliver of the navigation when it's collapsed and when it's open it slides behind the header anyway. The 70% width is meant so that the right edge does not cover the social icons. It's functioning precisely the way I intended it to. Also, the navigation is going to change after 768px anyway and will no longer be hidden off the side.

Comment: I just noticed that there was a space between the footer and the sidebar that there shouldn't be.

Comment: Interesting. What browser and window size are you viewing it in? In chrome, safari and firefox for me there's no space until 1000px wide or so, which doesn't matter since 768px and up will have a different style for the navigation altogether. Just haven't gotten that far yet :P

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('article.project').on('click','header',function(){
    _parent = $(this).parent();
    if(_parent.hasClass('clicked')){
        // If the clicked project has already been clicked, remove the class and hide the content
        _parent.removeClass('clicked');
               .find('.proj_content')
               .slideUp('fast');

    }else{
        // Remove the class and slide the content up on all projects
        $('article.project').removeClass('clicked')
                            .children('.proj_content')
                            .slideUp('fast');
        // Add the class and show the content on the selected project
        // Slide the project to the top after clicking on it
        _parent.addClass('clicked')
               .find('.proj_content')
               .slideDown('fast',function(){
                   // callback
                   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: +(_parent.offset().top)+'px' }, 500);
               });
    }

});
```

Comment: I tried this, however, I believe it conflicted with some of the jQuery I had set on the navigation. Ian's answer above seems to work fine. I appreciate the answer, nonetheless. Thanks a bunch!